# How can I convert the last column in svd.MatrixV() to 3 by 3 matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have obtained the 9th column in V matrix of singular value decomposition using:

`svd.matrixV().array().col(8)`

The column consists of 9 elements.
`3.6  -0.0148 -1.922  -4.177 0.0135 -0.00389 -2.29 -0.98  0.21`

Is there away in Eigen that can convert the 9 element column of svd.MatrixV() to 3 by 3 matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so using an [**`Eigen::Map`**](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) [as follows](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshapeSlicing.html):

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf> col_map {svd.matrixV().array().col(8).data(), 3, 3};
```

This map can then be assigned to a new matrix

```
Eigen::MatrixXf col_mat {col_map};
```